# Buying a software tool - should I buy myself or should the client do so

Tags: software

I'm working on a project as a freelancer. The project is already mature enough and the client wants to localize. I found a software tool on the web that will speed up localization greatly, but it costs money. I have never faced such question before. What is the right thing to do - buy the tool myself or ask my client to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it appropriate for a prospective client to require me to purchase third-party tools?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/764/is-it-appropriate-for-a-prospective-client-to-require-me-to-purchase-third-party)

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate, because in this case OP is advocating for the software, not being required to purchase.

Comment: Yes, really it is my own initiative to use the tool. The client's requirement is just to localize and localization can be done manually but it will be long lasting process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big a difference is the return? Let's say the tool costs $2,000 and the project is billed at $1,000, then the client should cover cost as it is specific to his project, definitely so if it's a one off task.

If on the other hand you think the tool can be used again with other projects and the such then I would say, cover the costs, so you avoid using a client's tool for another client's project.